# Drop xml declaration in libxml2

Tags: c, libxml2

I want to get rid of the xml declaration when I use libxml2's function xmlSaveFile. How can I accomplish that ?
Is there any macro to do that or can I use another function (I tried with xmlSaveToFilename from xmlsave.h but I do not know how it works) ?

Comment: Why? It shouldn't be doing any harm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
xmlSaveCtxtPtr saveCtxt = xmlSaveToFilename(filename, NULL, XML_SAVE_NO_DECL);
if (saveCtxt == NULL) {
    // Error handling
}
if (xmlSaveDoc(saveCtxt, doc) < 0) {
    // Error handling
}
xmlSaveClose(saveCtxt);
```

The documentation of the xmlsave module can be [found here](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlsave.html).

Comment: I used it but I cannot get it to work. How can I specify that I want to save a particular xmlDocPtr, it does not appear in the parameters of xmlSaveToFilename ?

Comment: The `xmlDocPtr` is passed as second argument to `xmlSaveDoc`.

Comment: Agreeing with this answer, it worked fine for me, so I declared it in my project (a small library that extends libxml2): https://github.com/silvioprog/ws/blob/master/libmicroxml/src/microxml.c#L513.